# How to get visually distinguishable colors from line graphs

Tags: image-processing, colors

I am looking at a problem, where I want to know how many colors a scientific chart contains. For example, consider the image [image]

. While there are four (red, green, blue and black) visually distinguishable colors here, according to the pixels, there are more than 1000 colors. What would be some ways I can tackle this problem?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106190/algorithm-challenge-generate-color-scheme-from-an-image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526729/algorithm-design-image-quantization-for-most-prominent-colors and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290259/detect-main-colors-in-an-image-with-php